# Setup node js server on Fedora 27

Tags: node.js, server, routes, fedora

I'm trying to setup node js app on Fedora 27 server with workstation GUI. I'm using old router D-Link 250N. I've managed to establish ssh connection via port forwarding on router, SFTP also. I read a lot about reverse proxy and nginx but how can I serve node app only from this one PC?

I've tried to open port 3000 run express on localhost:3000 and then port forward from router IP to local machine but without effects.

Ofc pc has static IP, my goal for now is to see express's "hello world" using url https://routerExternalIP:3000 - or other specified port.

I'm going to use pm2 for automation.

Answer (score 0):

Change your base URL in your express server config from http://localhost:3000 to http://0.0.0.0:3000.  This should allow requests from outside the local machine.

example:
server.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0")

Comment: Still doesn't work, "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" I think even when i open ports using "ufw" they still blocked or something, tomorrow I will try check it using fedora cockpit.

Comment: If you haven’t already, enable logging on ufw (sudo ufw logging on) which will let you see if ufw is blocking in /var/log/ufw.log

Comment: Nevermind, the whole problem was that in the real unlocking ports with ssh don't unlock them i had to do this manually and then everything was ok.